# after renaming my wp-content folder, how do I upgrade my wordpress version?

Tags: theme-development, functions, upgrade

I renamed my wp-content folder in an earlier version of WordPress. Now, I've upgraded my WordPress to the new version, but after the upgrad, I could not access the my active theme and plugin sub-folders of the wp-content anymore.

What should I do? (I have forgotten how i did the customization - it is over 9 months now)

I want to revert back to the default WordPress folders so I can upgrade to the new version of WordPress successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the contents from old renamed folder into wp-content folder which is created by your latest wordpress installation.